# Correct ID validation in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently creating a student attendance system using c# and MySQL.
There is a barcode scanner to scan student id. i have stored student information in `std_info` column and attendance information in `std_att` column. The scanning and adding is working perfectly. The barcode scanner is scanning the student id number.

How can it be modified to show an error message if the barcode scanner went wrong and someone add data that is not in the database?

Here is the code for add to database:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into std_att (nibm_id, nic, name, address, number, batch) SELECT * FROM `std_info` where nibm_id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                label10.Text = "*Please scan the ID";
                errorProvider1.Clear();
               
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted ✔️");

                string Query = "select * from std_att ;";
                MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
            }
        }
```

Barcode scanning part

```
  private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
            var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            if (result != null)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                {

                    cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM `std_info` where nibm_id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                        label3.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        label4.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        label8.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();

                }
                        con.Close();

                }));

            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }
```

[image: Screen shot of the program]

Comment: if `dr.Read()` is `false` the first time you call it, then there are no rows in the query result.

Comment: What is the actual question? For code reviews see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As Llama said in their comment

```
if(!dr.Read())
{
/* No rows returned from query - run your error code in here */
}
```

Note that `dr.Read()` will advance the reader to the next record, so you'll need an else statement to catch the first record if `dr.Read()` returns `true`.

You should probably also use `using` statements around your `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` statements to ensure they get disposed of properly.